# Push process builder to gitHub

Tags: process-builder, github

I am trying to find a way to push a process builder flow to github.com.

I know how we can push code to github but anyone has idea how can I push process builder flow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to include the metadata.

Process Builder metadata can be found under the type: Flow

Read this : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm

Answer (score 1):

Process builder flows are stored in the metadata `FlowDefinition` object

Include the `FlowDefinition` meta object in your Projet and do a refresh to get them in local

then you can push them to github